# How to apply line segment detector (LSD) on a video , frame by frame?

Tags: c, opencv, video-processing

```
int main()
{
  image_double image;
  ntuple_list out;
  unsigned int xsize,ysize,depth;
  int x,y,i,j,width,height,step;
  uchar *p;
  IplImage* img = 0; 
  IplImage* dst = 0;
  img = cvLoadImage("D:\\Ahram.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  width = img->width;
  height = img->height;
  dst=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
  cvCvtColor(img,dst,CV_RGB2GRAY);

  width=dst->width;
  height=dst->height;
  step=dst->widthstep;
  p=(uchar*)dst->imageData;
  image=new_image_double(dst->width,dst->height);
  xsize=dst->width;
  for(i=0;i<height;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<width;j++)
      {
         image->data[i+j*xsize]=p[i*step+j];

      }

  }


/* call LSD */

out = lsd(dst);

  /* print output */
  printf("%u line segments found:\n",out->size);
  for(i=0;i<out->size;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<out->dim;j++)
        printf("%f ",out->values[ i * out->dim + j ]);
      printf("\n");
    }


  /* free memory */
  free_image_double(image);
  free_ntuple_list(out);

  return 0;
}
```

N.B:it has no errors but when i run it gives out an LSD internal error:invalid image input

Comment: I noticed your other question, now I see that you are calling LSD from the command-line. If you are trying to process video frames from OpeCV using this method, you'll have a difficult time making it work. A better approach is, *learn* how to use the LSD API and call it from the loop that reads frames from the camera.

Comment: There are comment links below each answer. Use those to engage in dialog. If you need to add additional detail, add it to your question.  Also, I've merged your duplicate accounts.  It might be worthwhile for you to spend a few minutes learning how this site works; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: You drastically changed your question from what it was originally. Ideally, you would ask another question reporting this behavior you observed. The problem is that your original question has been answered, but if you keep changing the question, then my work is rendered useless. Revert the question to what it was, ask another question and I'll gladly try to help you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by researching [how PGM is structured](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html):

```
 Each PGM image consists of the following:
   1. A "magic number" for identifying the file type. 
      A pgm image's magic number is the two characters "P5".
   2. Whitespace (blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs).
   3. A width, formatted as ASCII characters in decimal.
   4. Whitespace.
   5. A height, again in ASCII decimal.
   6. Whitespace.
   7. The maximum gray value (Maxval), again in ASCII decimal. 
      Must be less than 65536, and more than zero.
   8. A single whitespace character (usually a newline).
   9. A raster of Height rows, in order from top to bottom. 
      Each row consists of Width gray values, in order from left to right. 
      Each gray value is a number from 0 through Maxval, with 0 being black 
       and Maxval being white. Each gray value is represented in pure binary 
       by either 1 or 2 bytes. If the Maxval is less than 256, it is 1 byte. 
      Otherwise, it is 2 bytes. The most significant byte is first.
```

For PGM type P2, pixels are readable (ASCII) on the file, but for P5 they won't be because they will be stored in binary format.

**One important thing** you should know, is that this format takes only 1 channel per pixel. This means PGM can only store **GREY** scaled **images**. Remember this!

Now,  if you're using OpenCV to load images from a file, you should load them using **CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE**:

```
IplImage* cv_img = cvLoadImage("chairs.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(!cv_img)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: cvLoadImage failed" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

But if you use any other flag on this function or if you create an image with `cvCreateImage()`, or if you're capturing frames from a camera or something like that, you'll need to **convert each frame to its grayscale** representation using `cvCvtColor()`.

I downloaded *lsd-1.5* and noticed that there is an example there that shows how to use the library. One of the source code files, named **lsd_cmd.c**, manually reads a PGM file and assembles an `image_double` with it. The function that does this trick is `read_pgm_image_double()`, and it reads the pixels from a PGM file and stores them inside `image->data`. This is important because if the following does not work, you'll have to iterate on the pixels of `IplImage` and do this yourself.

After successfully loading a gray scaled image into `IplImage* cv_img`, you can try to create the structure you need with:

```
image_double image = new_image_double(cv_img->width, cv_img->height); 
image->data = (double) cv_img->imageData;
```

In case this doesn't work, you'll need to check the file I suggested above and iterate through the pixels of `cv_img->imageData` and copy them one by one (doing the proper type conversion) to `image->data`.

At the end, don't forget to free this resource when you're done using it:

```
free_image_double(image);
```

Comment: Thanks Karlphilip, but iam sorry because i didn't understand my problem well, my real problem is to convert the image_double structure in (LSD) into Ipl structure to accept Ipl frames from opencv (capture frames from a camera using opencv), i read your answer and got the idea, if you can give me more clarification about the real issue, you well make to me a great favor.thanks

Comment: @Eslam Changing the entire LSD to accept *IplImage* instead of *image_double* is simply too much work. Let's be clear about what operations are involved in the task at hand. You are using opencv to capture frames from the camera, and you need to use LSD functions on these frames, right? After LSD is done, you need to get the result and convert it back to *IplImage* (to display on the screen or whatever). Does that make sense to you? Is this what you want to do?

Comment: A great deal of my answer was dedicated to show exactly how the conversion is done between these 2 data types. My examples showed how to do it in one direction: `IplImage*` to `image_double`. To perform the other conversion, you need to either create a new `IplImage*` or use the original frame to store the result of `image->data`. This is not an easy question, so don't expect an easy answer. Take your time and read my answer carefully, as many times as you need to understand what you have to do.

Comment: Thanks Karlphilip, now we are together on the right way, my target is to capture video from camera using opencv and process LSD on the frames of the video,you are right, i know how to iterate through pixels in IpLImage to store them in image->data (image_double),but i didn't know how to manipulate pixels in image_double structure in order to write IPlImage pixels in it(i.e how he write pixels in image_double?).thanks best regards, Eslam

Answer (score 0):

This question helped me some time ago. You probably solved it already so sorry for the delay but i'm sharing now the answer.

I'm using lsd 1.6 and the lsd interface is a little different from the one you are using (they changed the lsd function interface from 1.5 to 1.6).

```
CvCapture* capture;
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture (0);
assert( capture != NULL );

//get capture properties
int width  = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int height = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

//create OpenCV image structs
IplImage *frame;
IplImage *frameBW = cvCreateImage( cvSize( width, height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );

//create LSD image type
double *image;
image = (double *) malloc( width * height * sizeof(double) );

while (1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) break;

    //convert to grayscale
    cvCvtColor( frame , frameBW, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //cast into LSD image type
    uchar *data = (uchar *)frameBW->imageData;
    for (i=0;i<width;i++){
    for(j=0;j<height;j++){
        image[ i + j * width ] = data[ i + j * width];
    }
    }

    //run LSD
    double *list;
    int n;
    list = lsd( &n, image, width, height );

    //DO PROCESSING DRAWING ETC

    //draw segments on frame
    for (int j=0; j<n ; j++){       
        //define segment end-points
        CvPoint pt1 = cvPoint(list[ 0 + j * 7 ],list[ 1 + j * 7 ]);
        CvPoint pt2 = cvPoint(list[ 2 + j * 7 ],list[ 3 + j * 7 ]);

        // draw line segment on frame
        cvLine(frame,pt1,pt2,CV_RGB(255,0,0),1.5,8,0);      
    }

    cvShowImage("FRAME WITH LSD",frame);

    //free memory
    free( (void *) list );

    char c = cvWaitKey(1);
    if( c == 27 ) break; // ESC QUITS
}
//free memory
free( (void *) image );

cvReleaseImage( &frame );
cvReleaseImage( &frameBW );
cvDestroyWindow( "FRAME WITH LSD");
```

Hope this helps you or someone in the future! LSD works really great.